# How does .add() work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this method used to add new element? Or is this just misuderstanding. How does it work?

```
     <div class="firstDiv">
      text in first div
     </div>
```

After I run the following :

```
$( ".firstDiv" ).add( "p" ).text("new paragraph");
```

The browser shows `new paragraph`, but where is `text in first div` goes?

Thanks

Comment: try it out in plnkr of fiddle?

Comment: `.text("new paragraph");` removes the existing content and replaces it with  the passed text content

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [relevant documentation?](https://api.jquery.com/add/).

Comment: @Lix, yes but sometimes beginner like me doesn't get it well

Comment: @hansf. - and that is acceptable :) You do however have to be a little more specific with what exactly you are having problems with. If there is a specific part of the documentation that doesn't quite make sense to you, you could ask about that. As it currently stands, your question simply doesn't show much research effort on your side; That's also probably the reason for the down votes...

Comment: I don't know exactly how to ask good question since you know we ask "this" wrong , we ask "that" is also wrong, isn't the question  clear enough.

Comment: @hansf. people do complain alot but that is needed to keep the site clean, it's nothing personal at all so don't worry. If you're new to the site it's abit difficult to get used to the way questions are asked especially since it's already an evolved (kind of) forum. You'll get it right over time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.add()` method is used to add elements to the current selection and the [docs are here](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

**usage:**

```
var $collection = $('div').add('p');
```

`$collection` now contains all the `div` elements and all the `p` elements in the document

Comment: no problem, glad I could help. @Satpal's answer gives you want you need Re: the fix

Answer (score 3):

I think you need [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$( ".firstDiv" ).append( $("<p/>").text("new paragraph"));
```

[`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) is for different purpose.

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

`.add` does not mean "append a new element". Instead [it means](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

This is what you wanted:

```
$("<p>").text("new paragraph").appendTo(".firstDiv");
```